# Multiple drop down menu query results when left null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drop-down-menu

I'm new to php and I'm having a problem.

I have three drop down menus to sort results, but I want to make it so if they dont choose anything the defaults is a SELECT * FROM restaurant and if only one drop down is selected to only consider that field.

```
<form id="form" name="vicinity" method="post" action="restaurant-list.php">
   <select class="form-banner" size="1" id="vicinity" name="vicinity">
      <option value=""> Select one </option>
      <option value="Back Bay">Back Bay</option>
      <option value="Beacon Hill">Beacon Hill</option>
      <option value="Chinatown">Chinatown</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <p class="font-2">Search by Cuisines</p>
   <select class="form-banner" size="1" id="cuisine" name="cuisine">
      <option value=""> Select one </option>
      <option value="American">American</option>
      <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
      <option value="Indian">Indian</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <p class="font-2">Search by Price</p>
   <select class="form-banner" size="1"  id="price" name="price">
      <option value=""> Select one </option>
      <option value="$">$ - Cheap</option>
      <option value="$$">$$ - Moderate</option>
      <option value="$$$">$$$ - Pricey</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <input type="submit" id="banner-search" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

the restaurants page (currently only works when all fields are selected) if one is left blank nothing displays.

```
<?php
require ("db.php");
$vicinity = $_POST["vicinity"];
$cuisine = $_POST["cuisine"];
$price = $_POST["price"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE vicinity=\"$vicinity\" AND cuisine=\"$cuisine\" AND price=\"$price\"";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Any help or ideas how can I achieve this.

Comment: i know you're just a beginner, but you might as well start off correctly. do not code your sql in your code. you will be vulnerable to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection . what you need is a stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure in your PHP Code do this: (edited to show one step in preventing injection)

```
<?php
require ("db.php");
$vicinity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["vicinity"]);
$cuisine = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["cuisine"]);
$price = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["price"]);

$query = "SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE 1=1 ";
if($vicinity) $query .= "AND vicinity=\"$vicinity\" ";
if($cuisine)  $query .= "AND cuisine=\"$cuisine\" ";
if($price)    $query .= "AND price=\"$price\"";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Putting the 1=1 after the where just makes it so you don't have to worry about testing to see if you need an AND or not in front of your where statements and it won't change your query results.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do if your SQL db supports the LIKE statement.

```
<?php
require ("db.php");
$vicinity = $_POST["vicinity"];
$cuisine = $_POST["cuisine"];
$price = $_POST["price"];

$query = "SELECT * FROM restaurant WHERE vicinity LIKE \"%$vicinity%\" AND cuisine LIKE \"%$cuisine%\" AND price LIKE \"%$price\%"";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Beware, with this you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

To prevent it you should be check if your inputs have any data and build the query depending if they contain some of your values or not with some SQL Framework (Zend_Db maybe) or escaping the values of your variables.